# What is the error in the following Java-code?

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
    class Huffman  {
        int a;
        public Huffman(int i)
        {
            a = i;
        }               
    }

    class PriorityQueueDemo implements Comparator<Huffman>
    {
        public int compare(Huffman ab, Huffman cd)
        {
            if(ab.a>cd.a)
            {
                return 1;

            }
            return 0;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {
            PriorityQueue<Huffman> HuffQueue = new PriorityQueue<Huffman>();

            Huffman ab = new Huffman(10);
            HuffQueue.offer(ab);
            ab = new Huffman(50);
            HuffQueue.offer(ab);
            ab = new Huffman(20);
            HuffQueue.offer(ab);
            ab = new Huffman(60);
            HuffQueue.offer(ab);


            while(HuffQueue.size() > 0)
                   System.out.println(HuffQueue.remove());

            }
    }
```

What is wrong with the following Code! It generates the following **exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Huffman cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at PriorityQueueDemo.main(Huffman.java:34)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement `Comparable` interface

> A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

Or you need to pass comparator in constructor

[`public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

like as follows

```
PriorityQueue<Huffman> HuffQueue = new PriorityQueue<Huffman>(10, new Comparator<Huffman>(){

@Override
public int compare(Huffman ab, Huffman cd){
            if(ab.a>cd.a)
            {
                return 1;

            }
            return 0;
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its working now but the order in which it is printing is not as PRIORITY-Queue. Its output is in the same order as of insertion. What wrong with it???

Comment: Check it with your `compare()` method

Answer (score 0):

Exception states `Hufmann`class is not `Comparable`, does not implement `java.util.Comparable`, as required by the `PriorityQueue`. Implement `Comparable` into `Huffman` in order to be comparable and get proper priority onto queue. `Comparable` is explained in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html and requires a `compareTo(T o) : int` method implementation.

Comment: if(ab.a>cd.a)
{
                return 1;
}
return 0;

when i replaced this code with:

 return ab.a-cd.a;

it worked! what i understand from here is that it Compare expects the +ve or -ve value. If the first argument(already present element to whom the coming value is to be compared: recursively) is greater then the passed value, which is the correct order in that case it returns some -ve value. If it need to be swapped it should return a +ve value.